# How to create a large block of smaller images?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to format my tumbnails so that they form one larger square. Currently they're uncentered (which is my first issue), and have spaces between them. How would I go about centering the overall thumbnails, and then making it so that all the thumbnails would touch and form a square?

```css
.links {
 margin: auto;
 padding: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
img {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: auto; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 100px;
 
 } 

h2 {
 margin: 15% 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 5px; 
 font-size: 125%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Landscapes</h2>
<div id="links">
    <a href="img/landscapes/brs.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/brs.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/ela.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/ela.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/farm.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/farm.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/first.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/first.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/hf.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/hf.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/lindy.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/lindy.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/lp.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/lp.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/mcafee.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/mcafee.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/meth.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/meth.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
     <a href="img/landscapes/nr.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/nr.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/d.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/d.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="img/landscapes/old.jpg" title="">
        <img src="img/thumbnails/old.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Here's an image of what it currently looks like:

[image: currently]

The kind of thing I'm going for:

[image: desired]

Comment: Can you update your code snippet to use placeholder images? Since you've used local URLs for local image resources, we don't see any content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
a, img, div{
    display: inline-table;
}

.links {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

img {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: auto; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}   

h2 {
    margin: 15% 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    font-size: 125%;
    text-align: center;
} 
a{
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55cdek2r/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following and change .links to #links or set class = 'links' instead of id = 'links'

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px -2.5px;
}
```